# Is it possible to bypass the permission bit and execute software downloaded from a website?

Tags: software-installation

I want to know if it's possible to run software that has been downloaded from the internet. Ubuntu does not allow that but is it possible to set the executable permissions required for ? I recently downloaded software but it wont work due to this reason. Does anybody know of a way?

Answer (score 1):

When you download some executable package from the internet, by default it does not have executable permission.

To make you program execute, you need to assign executable permission to it.

To assign executable permissio to your file

- Open terminal and goto to the directory where file is downloaded. for example `cd ~/Downloads`.
- Now aasign executable permission to the file using `chmod +x filename`
- Now run it using `./filename`

Answer (score 0):

Try `chmod +x your-executable-file`.